# Error in execution DroidCam in Ubuntu

Tags: droidcam

while I am trying to run DroidCam it shows as here:
[image: Error]

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Secure Boot in your BIOS should be disabled for this install to work since it is not signed.    Go to the folder where you extracted the DroidCam and run `sudo ./install`  Then you should be able to just type in `droidcam` from a terminal and run it normally.

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cd Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit$ ls
droidcam  droidcam-cli  install  README  uninstall  v4l2loopback
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit$ sudo ./install
[sudo] password for terrance: 
Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
make: Entering directory '/home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback'
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
Makefile:975: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback'
Moving driver and executable to system folders
Registering webcam device
Running depmod
make: Entering directory '/home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback'
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
  CLEAN   /home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/.tmp_versions
  CLEAN   /home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/Module.symvers
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/home/terrance/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback'
Adding uninstall script
Adding driver to /etc/modules
Done
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/Downloads/droidcam/droidcam-64bit$ droidcam
```

[image]

Comment: if i use ./install it shows:
sudo ./install
Moving driver and executable to system folders
Registering webcam device
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko: Required key not available

Comment: @mdrahman Try installing dkms `sudo apt install dkms` so the module can be inserted dynamically

Comment: still Same. output is as before

Comment: @MdRahman Ah, for the error see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/231142  Looks like you need to have Secure Boot disabled.